# How can I copy menu items in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, menuitem

So I'm making a web browsing app in Xcode for OS X, and right now I am working on history. I have a menu called history in my MainMenu.xib, and I was wondering if it would be possible to add a menu item (through coding) to that every time the user loads a new page. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
- (void)addHistoryItemWithTitle:(NSString *)title URL:(NSURL *)historyURL
    NSMenuItem *menuItem = [[[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:title action:@selector(goToHistoryItem:) keyEquivalent:@""] autorelease];
    menuItem.representedObject = historyURL;
    //Note: You would normally have an outlet for your History menu or use
    //      itemWithTag:, so that it works in localized versions of your app.
    NSMenuItem *historyMenuItem = [[NSApp mainMenu] itemWithTitle:@"History"];
    [[historyMenuItem submenu] addItem:menuItem];
}
```

In your action you could then retrieve the URL (or some other object) that you set as the `representedObject` before:

```
- (void)goToHistoryItem:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *historyURL = [sender representedObject];
    NSLog(@"history item selected: %@", historyURL);
}
```

Comment: What? It says ARC forbids [autorelease].

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I have been trying for the last four days to get this! Very helpful!